# amdgpu_cs_ioctl *ERROR* Failed to initialize parser -125!

Tags: amd-graphics

Sometimes when I connect my External USB Disk or try to move files from two internal disks I get this error msg and my PC is freeze.

```
[drm:amdgpu_cs_ioctl [amdgpu]] ERROR Failed to initialize parser -125!
```

[image]

Specs:

```
OS: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia
Kernel: 5.3.0-28-generic

GPU: XFX Radeon RX570 RS Black Edition 8.0 GB
    How can i fix this problem?
    If i install amdgpu-pro the problem it will be fix?
```

Answer (score 1):

This bug report explains what is happening https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205089